# How do I control the session expiry in Tomcat with auth DIGEST

Tags: tomcat, digest-authentication

My web.xml includes

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method>
    <realm-name>My realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Which correctly pops up an authentication window in the browser. How do I control how long this authentication is valid? I've tested restarting Tomcat, and restarting the browser but this doesn't reset. So I imagine there is a cookie somewhere.

Can anyone point me to some documentation on best practices?

Answer (score 1):

The session timeout is defined in web.xml. Which authentication method you use is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks! And the client side mechanism is a stored cookie of the session ID?